# Switchee | Matrix and MX Calculator

Tags: matrix, switchee, mx-calculator

I'm trying to use MX Calculate to perform a percentage calculation of each row in a matrix column and the percentage is based on the value that's in each row which I'm trying to get Switchee to recognize but I think my problem lies somewhere in the parse order but I can't figure it out. Here's the code:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{event_fee}" parse="inward"}

     {case value=">=1000"}
     <strong>
     $ {exp:mx_calc parse="inward" expression="{event_fee}/100*40"}
     </strong>
     {/case}

     {case value="<=999"}
     <strong>
     $ {exp:mx_calc parse="inward" expression="{event_fee}/100*30"}
     </strong>
     {/case}

 {/exp:switchee}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `{event_fee}` and what is `{fee}`?

Comment: Hi Jason. I'm sorry I made a correction the {fee} was suppose to be {event_fee}. The {event_fee} is a number field within matrix.

Comment: just a side note, this works perfectly fine: *$ {exp:mx_calc parse="inward" expression="{event_fee}/100*40"}* it's only when using Switchee there's no output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [forum post on Devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/switchee/viewthread/6134), you can't do less thans or greater thans inside the case values.
You'll need to use a regular expression.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html explains how to define numeric ranges.

But for your example, `case value="#^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$#"` should match 0-999. (Your regex needs to be enclosed with hashes).

If you are only using the two cases you mention, you might be better off using [IfElse](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse). I'm pretty sure you can use greater than and less than.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you'd probably be better off using [Ifelse](https://github.com/croxton/Ifelse) rather than Switchee. While you can certainly bodge all sorts of things with regular expressions, a switch statement isn't generally the way to go if you just want a simple `n < y` check.

```
{exp:ifelse parse="inward"} 
    {if event_fee < 1000}
        <strong>
        $ {exp:mx_calc parse="inward" expression="{event_fee}/100*30"}
        </strong>
    {if:else}
         <strong>
         $ {exp:mx_calc parse="inward" expression="{event_fee}/100*40"}
         </strong>
    {/if}
{/exp:ifelse}
```

The ifelse plugin will remove non-matching conditions before they're parsed, so you'll still only have one mx_calc call per row.

<sub>Edit: I've just noticed Jason's mentioned ifelse in his response already. I'll leave my answer here since the sample code might be useful.</sub>